# Gnuplot vs matlab plot streamlines

Tags: matlab, gnuplot

I am making a stream function plot with the following data points in gnuplot:

[Streamdata.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9CEsYCSSZUSTEFjNS1UdTJSZVE/view?usp=sharing)

My gnuplot code is working, but it plots to few streamlines compared when i plot it in matlab. See picture: (matlab plot on the left, gnuplot on the right)

[image: matlab plot on the left, gnuplot on the right]

Is there a way, so gnuplot can plot more streamlines? So the plot becomes more similar to the matlab plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnuplot has several options for adjusting how contours are drawn.  In your case, you need to adjust the levels option.

If we do

```
set cntrparam levels auto 10
```

and then plot we get

[image]

See `help cntrparam` for more details.

Comment: Nice thank you :) And a little side note, your plot is prettier than mine, is there a reason for that? Your streamlines appear more smooth, and mine more "pixel bumpy" like. http://imgur.com/258W3da

Comment: @euroshopper It's probably just the resolution on the terminal I used (wxt).  Other than that one extra command, I just ran the commands you provided.